# Option Clash for Hyperref Package

Tags: hyperref, option-clash

When I run this code, I'm getting the error:

> "! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref."

Code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}         
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths} 

\firstname{Rob}
\familyname{Ward}
\mobile{mobile +64 21 0377 936}                   
\phone{phone +64 6 212 0549}                      
\email{contact@robward.co.nz}                      
\homepage{www.robward.co.nz}                

\usepackage[pdftex,
            pdfauthor={Rob Ward},
            pdftitle={CV for Rob Ward},
            pdfsubject={Detailed CV for Rob},                   
            urlcolor={blue}]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

% EDUCATION
\section{Education}
\cventry{2006--2011}{PhD physics/biophysics}{Massey University}{Palmerston North}{New Zealand}{}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{1999--2004}{BSc (hons.) physics}{Victoria University}{Wellington}{New Zealand}{}
\cventry{1999--2002}{BSc mathematics}{Victoria University}{Wellington}{New Zealand}{}
\cventry{1988--1989}{NCEE}{Central Institute of Technology}{Wellington}{New Zealand}{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 52):

**Update:** `moderncv` loads the package `hyperref` by itself with its own `hypersetup`. From `moderncv.cls`,

[image]

Hence, you need not load `hyperref` again. But load the `hypersetup` using `\AfterPreamble` (or `\AtBeginDocument`)  hook as in this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}

\firstname{Rob}
\familyname{Ward}
\mobile{mobile +64 21 0377 936}
\phone{phone +64 6 212 0549}
\email{contact@robward.co.nz}
\homepage{www.robward.co.nz}

\AfterPreamble{\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={Rob Ward},
  pdftitle={CV for Rob Ward},
  pdfsubject={Detailed CV for Rob},
  urlcolor=blue,
}}

\begin{document}


% EDUCATION
\section{Education}
\cventry{2006--2011}{PhD physics/biophysics}{Massey University}{Palmerston
North}{New Zealand}{}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{1999--2004}{BSc (hons.) physics}{Victoria
University}{Wellington}{New Zealand}{}
\cventry{1999--2002}{BSc mathematics}{Victoria University}{Wellington}{New
Zealand}{}
\cventry{1988--1989}{NCEE}{Central Institute of Technology}{Wellington}{New
Zealand}{}

\end{document}
```

The pdf properties will then look like:

[image]

**Earlier attempt:**

```
   \PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex,
            pdfauthor={Rob Ward},
            pdftitle={CV for Rob Ward},
            pdfsubject={Detailed CV for Rob},
            urlcolor={blue}}{hyperref}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}

\firstname{Rob}
\familyname{Ward}
\mobile{mobile +64 21 0377 936}
\phone{phone +64 6 212 0549}
\email{contact@robward.co.nz}
\homepage{www.robward.co.nz}

%\usepackage[pdftex,
%            pdfauthor={Rob Ward},
%            pdftitle={CV for Rob Ward},
%            pdfsubject={Detailed CV for Rob},
%            urlcolor={blue}]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

% EDUCATION
\section{Education}
\cventry{2006--2011}{PhD physics/biophysics}{Massey University}{Palmerston North}{New Zealand}{}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{1999--2004}{BSc (hons.) physics}{Victoria University}{Wellington}{New Zealand}{}
\cventry{1999--2002}{BSc mathematics}{Victoria University}{Wellington}{New Zealand}{}
\cventry{1988--1989}{NCEE}{Central Institute of Technology}{Wellington}{New Zealand}{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** Noting the comments of Heiko Oberdiek,

> Package hyperref does a lot of redefinitions in order to support
>   non-ASCII stuff in strings for bookmarks and entries in the
>   information dictionary of PDF files. Much of this support gets lost,
>   if LaTeX expands the options the hard way before hyperref has a chance
>   to see them. Therefore it is better to set the information entries
>   after hyperref is loaded.

this is not always advisable. *In this case, it won't give desired results as the `hypersetup` is over-written later by the `moderncv` itself*.

Comment: Package `hyperref` does a lot of redefinitions in order to support non-ASCII stuff in strings for bookmarks and entries in the information dictionary of PDF files. Much of this support gets lost, if LaTeX expands the options the hard way before `hyperref` has a chance to see them. Therefore it is better to set the information entries _after_ `hyperref` is loaded.

Comment: Same problem with style `attachfile`. It loads `hyperref` as well which raises the clash error when trying to use `\hypersetup`. Easy solution for that style: first load `hyperref`, then load `attachfile`.

Answer (score 8):

In this case this can be solved by:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={...},
  pdftitle={...},
  pdfsubject={...},
  urlcolor=blue,
}
```

The entries for the PDF information dictionary should be better set after the package is loaded. Also the other entries (`urlcolor`) can be set afterwards. `pdftex` is not needed, `hyperref` detects pdfTeX in PDF mode automatically.

Generic methods to solve option clashes are
- `\PassOptionsToPackage` before the first loading of the package.
- Adding all options needed in the first loading of the package (not always possible,
  if the package is loaded indirectly).

### The full example

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}

\firstname{Rob}
\familyname{Ward}
\mobile{mobile +64 21 0377 936}
\phone{phone +64 6 212 0549}
\email{contact@robward.co.nz}
\homepage{www.robward.co.nz}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={Rob Ward},
  pdftitle={CV for Rob Ward},
  pdfsubject={Detailed CV for Rob},
  urlcolor=blue,
}

\begin{document}

% EDUCATION
\section{Education}
\cventry{2006--2011}{PhD physics/biophysics}{Massey University}{Palmerston
North}{New Zealand}{}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{1999--2004}{BSc (hons.) physics}{Victoria
University}{Wellington}{New Zealand}{}
\cventry{1999--2002}{BSc mathematics}{Victoria University}{Wellington}{New
Zealand}{}
\cventry{1988--1989}{NCEE}{Central Institute of Technology}{Wellington}{New
Zealand}{}

\end{document}
```

I do not get any option clash.

Comment: Hi Thanks , but i am still getting same error

Comment: Hi @Oberdiek,i am unable to rectify the same error even after implementing your correction.

Comment: @Ekaveera Which correction? Which error? Make a complete example that shows the problem. Maybe also add `\listfiles` to get a list of packages/classes with versions at the end of the LaTeX run.

Comment: Hi @Oberdiek i am talking about the same error "Option clash for Package hyperref" even after running the code given by you.i am using Texworks as an editor,not command line. so where can i put \listfiles in the editor? should i include before \begin{document}.

Comment: @Ekaveera That's not possible, unless you explicitly load `hyperref` with options or the class `moderncv` loads `hyperref` several times with different options (unlikely) or you are loading other packages that implicitly load `hyperref` with options. Anyway you have to update your example in the question.

Comment: Ok Thank you, i will try to solve and will get back to you..

Comment: @heiko oberdiek: moderncv does indeed load hyperref, and also does its own \hypersetup.  Ekaveera's simple \usepackage{hyperref} is enough to provoke the error message, i would think.

Comment: @wasteofspace No, only if a package is loaded with options that are not given before, the option clash error is raised.