# option clash hyper ref colorlinks and transparent

Tags: beamer, hyperref, option-clash, transparent

I get an option clash between the `hyperref` option `colorlinks` when I load `transparent` (before or after).  Here are the other packages I load.

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textpos}
```

My workaround for now is to just not use the `hyperref` package because I don't need it that bad, but I'm curious.  Neither [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79395/option-clash-for-hyperref-package) nor [this quite comprehensive question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before) (nor even the link to the documentation in it) seem to have any indication that `transparent` would cause trouble.  But knowing LaTeX (and especially `beamer`'s habit of loading the kitchen sink), it could be anything!

Hopefully no one will object to the absence of a MWE since the point is that nothing Ws in my Es with these packages, M or otherwise.

Comment: The fact that you get that warning means that hyperref is already loaded (by beamer actually) so the `\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}` line, if it did not generate an error, would do nothing at all as latex never includes a package twice. So deleting this line is a good fix but not because "you do not need hyperref" but rather because hyperref is already loaded.

Comment: The W does not mean it has to be working, rather that it should work in theory. Therefore it would have been nice to make a complete document, including `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` instead of a code fragment, which everbody willing to help you first has to fix before starting with your actual problem.

Comment: Yes, I understand that very well, but we all have time limitations as well, and I believe all that was missing was the begin/end doc.  (Tested now that I have a more stable connection.)

Comment: Aargh, what doesn't beamer load?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hyperref` is already in the "kitchen sink", as you called it - so no need to load it yourself (and provoke the option clash), just pass the options you want via `hyperref={colorlinks}` to the beamer class.

Btw: `color` and `graphicx` are also in the "kitchen sink", so not necessary. Probably `\usepackage{multicol}` is also unnecessary, as beamer has its own columns mechanism.

```
\documentclass[english,hyperref={colorlinks}]{beamer}
%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{sagetex}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{transparent}
%\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textpos}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

> Warning:

Using `colourlinks` will destroy the carefully chosen colours of most beamer themes. Please check carefully if everything is still readable and consistent with the chosen colour scheme. Also you will no longer be able to use the `\setbeamercolor` mechanism to control the colour of certain elements.

Cautionary tale:

```
\documentclass[
hyperref={colorlinks}
]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

-> the red link colour is hard to read on the dark background.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't `beamer` enable `colorlinks` by default?

Comment: @AlexG No, have a look at the link colour of the naviagtion bar in the following example: `\documentclass[
hyperref={colorlinks}
]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
 
\section{test}
\begin{frame}
 abc
\end{frame} 
 
\end{document}`

Comment: @AlexG Oh, I know this feeling very well! I have it every time I read one of your `PDF Specification` voodoo answers :)

Comment: Thanks, but that is a piece of cake as compared to understanding TeX.

Comment: @AlexG I guess you are biased :)

Comment: I wanted the color links in the main text, if I recall correctly from the earlier document I copied these from. (Took two docs that worked great and merged them, more or less.)

Comment: Hilarious.  Basically the message is "don't mess with beamer".