# tex noob need help for a cv

Tags: hyperref, packages

someone can run this and tell me where is the error? :D

```
documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
% moderncv themes
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                  % optional argument are 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'roman' (for roman fonts, instead of sans serif fonts)
%\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                % idem

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                     % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\maketitlenamewidth}{6cm}}  % only for the classic theme, if you want to change the width of your name placeholder (to leave more space for your address details
%\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}                     % required when changes are made to page layout lengths

% Hyperlinks
\usepackage{hyperref}                               % to use hyperlinks
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}            % hyperlinks setup
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

% personal data
\firstname{Gianluca}
\familyname{Colombo}
%\title{Resumé title (optional)}               % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\address{Via Madonna della Salute 39}{25129 Padova, PD Italia}    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\mobile{+39 3492823493}                    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\phone{+39 049614143}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\fax{fax (optional)}                          % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\email{gianninc@gmail.com}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\email{\href{mailto:s.dakourou@gmail.com}{s.dakourou@gmail.com}}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\homepage{http://gr.linkedin.com/pub/stefania-dakourou/41/21a/396}%{LinkedIn Profile}}                % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{Patente B} % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                         % '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file; optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\quote{Some quote (optional)}                 % optional, remove the line if not wanted

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography; only useful if you make citations in your resume
.

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}

%\nopagenumbers{}                             % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Anagrafica}
\cvline{Luogo di nascita}{Nato a Dolo (VE) il 13 aprile 1985}
\cvline{Residenza}{ Via Madonna della salute 39 Padova}

\section{Educazione e Formazione}
%\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{Settembre 2010}{Musica elettronica Tecnico di sala di registrazione}{Conservatorio C.Pollini}{Padova}{in corso}{}
\cventry{Giugno 2010}{Corso formazione Steward}{Assist spa}{Padova}{}{}
\cventry{Giugno 2006}{Diploma Oracle Database Administrator}{corso FSE Ascom Servizi Padova SPA}{Informatica di base, gestione programma oracle, sql language,PLsql language}{}{}
\cventry{Settembre 2004}{Arte Musica e Spettacolo}{Università di Padova}{}{}{}
\cventry{Luglio 2004}{Diploma maturità Scientifica}{liceo scientifico L. da Vinci}{}{}{}

\section{Esperienze lavorative}
\cventry{Ottobre 2014}{Volontario}{Volontariato in trentino tramite wwoof}{http://www.horsetrekking.it/ e http://almasopercaso.blogspot.it/}{alimentazione degli animali, carpenteria di base}{}
\cventry{Giugno 2014--settembre 2014}{Impiegato livello V}{IC Outsourcing srl gruppo InfoCamere, Corso Stati Uniti 14}{Registratore con utilizzo di Personal computer e sue unità periferiche}{Uso di Software per bilanci aziendali}{}
\cventry{Aprile 2014}{Volontario}{Volontariato in una fattoria in Svezia tramite wwoof}{http://backasgard.blogspot.it}{alimentazione degli animali, carpenteria di base}{}
\cventry{Ottobre 2013--aprile 2014}{Commis di cucina e barista}{Black and white srl, Corso Vittorio Emanuele 185 Padova}{Gestione del Courage pub, cucina e sala}{}{}
\cventry{Maggio 2013--ottobre 2013}{Impiegato livello V}{IC Outsourcing srl gruppo InfoCamere, Corso Stati Uniti 14}{Registratore con utilizzo di Personal computer e sue unità periferiche}{Uso di Software per bilanci aziendali}{}
\cventry{2010--2012}{Tecnico di sala}{auditorium C. Pollini, Teatro la Fenice}{assistente di sala}{Sabat del conservatorio 2010-2013, Pacifica quartet, Nicola Bernardini, Ex Novo ensamble}{}
\cventry{Maggio 2008--agosto 2009}{Impiegato livello V}{IC Outsourcing srl gruppo InfoCamere, Corso Stati Uniti 14}{Registratore con utilizzo di Personal computer e sue unità periferiche}{Uso di Software per bilanci aziendali}{}
\cventry{Maggio 2006--agosto 2006}{Stage oracle database administrator}{Siav srl via rossi A Rubano (PD)}{Oracle database tuning/tester}{}{}
\cventry{Dicembre 2005--febbraio 2006}{Client finder-telefonista}{Euroscuola via Riello 1 Padova}{Telemarketing}{}{}
\cventry{Giugno 2005--agosto2008}{Promoter, Responsabile promoters}{Publinc DI.VA.}{Agenzia pubblicitaria}{Promozioni a spot}{}


\section{Lingue}
\cvlanguage{Italiano}{Madrelingua}{}
\cvlanguage{English}{Fluente}{}


\section{Computer skills}
\cvline{Basic}{\small HTML, sql plsql}
\cvline{Intermediate}{\small Csound}
\cvline{Expert}{\small Assemblaggio, Audio editing, Windows, Office, Linux, Mac}
%\cvcomputer{Basic}{HTML, sql plsql} {}{}
%\cvcomputer{Intermediate}{csound, c, octave, supercollider, ruby, pd, video editing}{}{}
%\cvcomputer{Expert}{Assemblaggio}

\section{Capacità e competenze personali}
\cvline{Competenze personali:}{Buone capacità relazionali,ottima capacità di lavoro di gruppo e indiduale.acquisite nell’area lavorativa e sportiva (basket,rugby,canoa). Sono capace di relazionarmi con il pubblico e/o privato poichè ho lavorato a stretto contatto con commercialisti fornitori e clienti.}
\cvline{Capacità e competenze organizzative:}{ Ho lavorato con Nicola Bernardini, Alvise Vidolin, e molti compositori di Musica Elettronica contemporanea come tecnico di sala, oltre a lavorare con l'ing Matteo Costa per affinare le mie capacità di amplificazione e registrazione di musica classica, concludendo anche mixaggi per varie enti radiotelevisive (rai radio2). Ho acquisito competenze organizzative grazie alla realizzazione di progetti all’interno del corso oracle database administrator. Ho fatto parte di un progetto di test in SIAV, collaborando alla realizzare della ricostruzione del database di un software aziendale. Sono capace di di organizzare autonomamente le mie vacanze e quelle dei miei amici utilizzando le varie forme di agevolazione proposte ai giovani.}{}
\cvline{Capacità e competenze artistiche:}{Frequenza a corsi di teatro, musica, cinema grazie all’università di Padova (dams) Ho realizzato un cortometraggio con un mio collega all’università organizzando le apparizioni. Realizzazioni Audio/video per esami in conservatorio C.Pollini.}
\cvline{Altre capacità e competenze:}{Manualità nel comprendere nuovi software grazie alla mia passione per il computer. Articolazione della struttura modulare del corso fse ORACLE database.Informatica di base.Sviluppo della società dell’informazione attraverso l’utilizzo di internet. Fondamenti giuridici. Diagnosticare, relazionarsi, affrontare. Introduzione ai sistemi di archiviazione, tipologie di database. Utilizzo di software Camerali.}{}
\cvline{Esperienze internazionali:}{Ho vissuto a Londra per 1 mese, ho visitato e viaggiato in Italia, Canada, America (CA), Irlanda, Francia, Spagna, Svezia, Albania, Croazia, Bosnia.}

\cvline{}{}
\cvline{}{}
\cvline{}{}
\cvline{}{Autorizzo il trattamento dei dati personali D.Lgs. Privacy n.196/03}



\end{document}
```

Comment: `moderncv` already loads the package `hyperref` by itself. Try: without `\usepackage{hyperref} ` and with`\AfterPreamble{\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}}`  - Possible duplicat: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79406/124842

Answer (score 1):

There are three things to fix in your code.

First, as @Bobyandbob said, the `moderncv` class already loads the `hyperref` package, so you should not.

Second, `hyperref` is loaded in a hook `\AtEndPreamble`, so the `\hypersetup` will throw an error unless you place it `\AtEndPreamble` too.

Third, there is a stray dot in your preamble (line 36) throwing a `Missing \begin{document}` error.

After the fixes it should look like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
% moderncv themes
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                  % optional argument are 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'roman' (for roman fonts, instead of sans serif fonts)
%\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                % idem

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                     % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\maketitlenamewidth}{6cm}}  % only for the classic theme, if you want to change the width of your name placeholder (to leave more space for your address details
%\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}                     % required when changes are made to page layout lengths

% Hyperlinks
% \usepackage{hyperref}% < ----- REMOVED HYPERREF FROM HERE
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}            % hyperlinks setup
\AtEndPreamble{\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}}% < ----- AtEndPreamble here

% personal data
\firstname{Gianluca}
\familyname{Colombo}
%\title{Resumé title (optional)}               % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\address{Via Madonna della Salute 39}{25129 Padova, PD Italia}    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\mobile{+39 3492823493}                    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\phone{+39 049614143}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\fax{fax (optional)}                          % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\email{gianninc@gmail.com}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\email{\href{mailto:s.dakourou@gmail.com}{s.dakourou@gmail.com}}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\homepage{http://gr.linkedin.com/pub/stefania-dakourou/41/21a/396}%{LinkedIn Profile}}                % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{Patente B} % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                         % '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file; optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\quote{Some quote (optional)}                 % optional, remove the line if not wanted

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography; only useful if you make citations in your resume
% . < ----- THIS DOT HERE

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}

%\nopagenumbers{}                             % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Anagrafica}
\cvline{Luogo di nascita}{Nato a Dolo (VE) il 13 aprile 1985}
\cvline{Residenza}{ Via Madonna della salute 39 Padova}

\section{Educazione e Formazione}
%\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{Settembre 2010}{Musica elettronica Tecnico di sala di registrazione}{Conservatorio C.Pollini}{Padova}{in corso}{}
\cventry{Giugno 2010}{Corso formazione Steward}{Assist spa}{Padova}{}{}
\cventry{Giugno 2006}{Diploma Oracle Database Administrator}{corso FSE Ascom Servizi Padova SPA}{Informatica di base, gestione programma oracle, sql language,PLsql language}{}{}
\cventry{Settembre 2004}{Arte Musica e Spettacolo}{Università di Padova}{}{}{}
\cventry{Luglio 2004}{Diploma maturità Scientifica}{liceo scientifico L. da Vinci}{}{}{}

\section{Esperienze lavorative}
\cventry{Ottobre 2014}{Volontario}{Volontariato in trentino tramite wwoof}{http://www.horsetrekking.it/ e http://almasopercaso.blogspot.it/}{alimentazione degli animali, carpenteria di base}{}
\cventry{Giugno 2014--settembre 2014}{Impiegato livello V}{IC Outsourcing srl gruppo InfoCamere, Corso Stati Uniti 14}{Registratore con utilizzo di Personal computer e sue unità periferiche}{Uso di Software per bilanci aziendali}{}
\cventry{Aprile 2014}{Volontario}{Volontariato in una fattoria in Svezia tramite wwoof}{http://backasgard.blogspot.it}{alimentazione degli animali, carpenteria di base}{}
\cventry{Ottobre 2013--aprile 2014}{Commis di cucina e barista}{Black and white srl, Corso Vittorio Emanuele 185 Padova}{Gestione del Courage pub, cucina e sala}{}{}
\cventry{Maggio 2013--ottobre 2013}{Impiegato livello V}{IC Outsourcing srl gruppo InfoCamere, Corso Stati Uniti 14}{Registratore con utilizzo di Personal computer e sue unità periferiche}{Uso di Software per bilanci aziendali}{}
\cventry{2010--2012}{Tecnico di sala}{auditorium C. Pollini, Teatro la Fenice}{assistente di sala}{Sabat del conservatorio 2010-2013, Pacifica quartet, Nicola Bernardini, Ex Novo ensamble}{}
\cventry{Maggio 2008--agosto 2009}{Impiegato livello V}{IC Outsourcing srl gruppo InfoCamere, Corso Stati Uniti 14}{Registratore con utilizzo di Personal computer e sue unità periferiche}{Uso di Software per bilanci aziendali}{}
\cventry{Maggio 2006--agosto 2006}{Stage oracle database administrator}{Siav srl via rossi A Rubano (PD)}{Oracle database tuning/tester}{}{}
\cventry{Dicembre 2005--febbraio 2006}{Client finder-telefonista}{Euroscuola via Riello 1 Padova}{Telemarketing}{}{}
\cventry{Giugno 2005--agosto2008}{Promoter, Responsabile promoters}{Publinc DI.VA.}{Agenzia pubblicitaria}{Promozioni a spot}{}


\section{Lingue}
\cvlanguage{Italiano}{Madrelingua}{}
\cvlanguage{English}{Fluente}{}


\section{Computer skills}
\cvline{Basic}{\small HTML, sql plsql}
\cvline{Intermediate}{\small Csound}
\cvline{Expert}{\small Assemblaggio, Audio editing, Windows, Office, Linux, Mac}
%\cvcomputer{Basic}{HTML, sql plsql} {}{}
%\cvcomputer{Intermediate}{csound, c, octave, supercollider, ruby, pd, video editing}{}{}
%\cvcomputer{Expert}{Assemblaggio}

\section{Capacità e competenze personali}
\cvline{Competenze personali:}{Buone capacità relazionali,ottima capacità di lavoro di gruppo e indiduale.acquisite nell’area lavorativa e sportiva (basket,rugby,canoa). Sono capace di relazionarmi con il pubblico e/o privato poichè ho lavorato a stretto contatto con commercialisti fornitori e clienti.}
\cvline{Capacità e competenze organizzative:}{ Ho lavorato con Nicola Bernardini, Alvise Vidolin, e molti compositori di Musica Elettronica contemporanea come tecnico di sala, oltre a lavorare con l'ing Matteo Costa per affinare le mie capacità di amplificazione e registrazione di musica classica, concludendo anche mixaggi per varie enti radiotelevisive (rai radio2). Ho acquisito competenze organizzative grazie alla realizzazione di progetti all’interno del corso oracle database administrator. Ho fatto parte di un progetto di test in SIAV, collaborando alla realizzare della ricostruzione del database di un software aziendale. Sono capace di di organizzare autonomamente le mie vacanze e quelle dei miei amici utilizzando le varie forme di agevolazione proposte ai giovani.}{}
\cvline{Capacità e competenze artistiche:}{Frequenza a corsi di teatro, musica, cinema grazie all’università di Padova (dams) Ho realizzato un cortometraggio con un mio collega all’università organizzando le apparizioni. Realizzazioni Audio/video per esami in conservatorio C.Pollini.}
\cvline{Altre capacità e competenze:}{Manualità nel comprendere nuovi software grazie alla mia passione per il computer. Articolazione della struttura modulare del corso fse ORACLE database.Informatica di base.Sviluppo della società dell’informazione attraverso l’utilizzo di internet. Fondamenti giuridici. Diagnosticare, relazionarsi, affrontare. Introduzione ai sistemi di archiviazione, tipologie di database. Utilizzo di software Camerali.}{}
\cvline{Esperienze internazionali:}{Ho vissuto a Londra per 1 mese, ho visitato e viaggiato in Italia, Canada, America (CA), Irlanda, Francia, Spagna, Svezia, Albania, Croazia, Bosnia.}

\cvline{}{}
\cvline{}{}
\cvline{}{}
\cvline{}{Autorizzo il trattamento dei dati personali D.Lgs. Privacy n.196/03}



\end{document}
```